# I'm doing codeacademy to learn some python, and I keep getting an error asking me if I've created a function called plane_ride_cost

Tags: python

I'm doing codeacademy to learn some python, and I keep getting an error asking me if I've created a function called `plane_ride_cost`.

```
#As you can see by the code below, I have in fact declared the function.       
def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        fee = 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        fee = 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        fee = 222
    elif city == "Los Angeles":
        fee = 475
    return fee
```

Comment: Are you trying to call the function before you defined it?

Comment: Please include the actual text of the error message, as well as any surrounding code that is relevant.

Comment: That's all the code that's relevant, and nowhere in the code do I ever call the method. For some reason codeacademy does that behind the scene or something. "Oops, try again. Did you create a function called plane_ride_cost?" is the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this is a Codecademy question, but just for the sake of completeness, here's an alternate, simple, relatively Pythonic way to do it:

```
def plane_ride_cost(city):
    choices = {                          # Make a dictionary of the choices.
        'Charlotte': 183,
        'Tampa': 220,
        'Pittsburgh': 222,
        'Los Angeles': 475
    }

    return choices.get(city, None)       # Look up the city in the dictionary.
                                         # Return None if the city isn't there.
```

I verified that [this works on the Codecademy example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiuOF.png).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't pass a city name that does not match any cities listed in the `if`, `elif` condition, you will get an exception.

```
>>> def plane_ride_cost(city):
...     if city == "Charlotte":
...         fee = 183
...     elif city == "Tampa":
...         fee = 220
...     elif city == "Pittsburgh":
...         fee = 222
...     elif city == "Los Angeles":
...         fee = 475
...     return fee
...
>>> plane_ride_cost('New York')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in plane_ride_cost
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fee' referenced before assignment
```

You need to handle `else` case or define `fee` before `if .. elif ..` statements.

Comment: So just write like `fee = 0` before all the `if .. elif ..` statements?

Comment: @JacobWillinger, Yes it is. Or `else: return 'No such city'` or `else: fee = 0`.

Comment: @JacobWillinger, BTW, Could you post the traceback? Without it, it's hard to guess what is the reason of the error.

Comment: I tried adding the `fee = 0` before the statements, but I get the error from codeacademy "It looks like plane_ride_cost does not return 220 when the city is Tampa."

Comment: @JacobWillinger, Can I get the link for the problem (codeacademy)?

Comment: @JacobWillinger, It's strange. With your code, I got "Way to go!". See http://i.imgur.com/NNUweYE.png

Comment: Hmm, weird. Well I'll probably just move past it then. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that the variable fee may not be defined if the value of city is different then the values you look for.

Comment: So add an else case in there?

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested, try adding an else

```
def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        fee = 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        fee = 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        fee = 222
    elif city == "Los Angeles":
        fee = 475
    else:
        return "There seems a problem with the city you've asked for!"
    return fee
```

Answer (score 0):

else is an optional
try this as well

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Tampa":
       return 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
       return 222
    elif city == "Charlotte":
       return 183
    elif city == "Los Angeles":
        return 475
print plane_ride_cost("Pittsburgh")

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> def plane_ride_cost(city):
>     if city == "Charlotte":
>         return 183
>     elif city == "Tampa":
>         return 220
>     elif city == "Pittsburgh":
>         return 222
>     elif city == "Los Angeles":
>         return 475
> ```

This is right for codecademy.com